# Hash Table Query

Tags: hash, hashtable

Can some one explain

> Given a hash table array of size N=11., and using a hash function -
>   **h(x) = 3 x + 7 mod N**
>
> Together with linear probing, the following sequence of operations are
>   performed:
>
> insert 5, insert 15, insert 4, insert 8, insert 7, insert 12
>
> What is the final state of the hash table?

---

*By my logic* 
 
**h(5) = (3*5) + (7 mod 11) = 15 + 7 = 22** so place in table[0]
**h(15) = (3*15) + (7 mod 11) = 45 + 7 = 52** so place in array[0]..cant so put in table[1]

etc.

But apparently my method is wrong. - e.g. h(15) places 15 in table[8]

 What have I failed to account for?

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mod 11 the answer! Simple mistake.
**h(5) = ((3*5) + 7) mod 11 = 15 + 7 = 22 -> 22 mod 11 = 0** so place in table[0]
**h(15) = ((3*15) + 7) mod 11 = 45 + 7 = 52 -> 52 mod 11 = 8** so place in array[8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your hash function should be (3x+7) mod N, not 3x + (7 mod N).

Comment: That would make much more sense! It's been a long day.